# Perl regex replace with UTF-8 characters

Tags: regex, perl, utf-8, character-encoding, diacritics

I despair on a function that I try to write with `Perl`. My function is to filter a string for specific characters. I allow some characters like `A-Z, a-z, 0-9` and I want also allow some german umlauts. But every time I define them in my regular expression, the replacement fails.

My encoding is `UTF-8` (server, perl, scripts).

This is my function:

```
sub cleanXSS{

    my $string = shift;

    $string =~ s/[^A-Za-z0-9öäü]//g;

    return $string;
}
```

My script looks like this:

```
my $scalar = "áéíóúÁÉÍüÓÚâêÄîôßû()ÂÊÎÔÛabcäüöÄÜÖý#µzdjheäöü";
print cleanXSS($scalar)."\n";
```

So it should replace all characters except `A-Z, a-z, 0-9` and lower case umlauts. The replacement for german umlauts in my test string works fine, but it seems that all other latin characters were only replaced partially.

The console output looks like this:

```
▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ü▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒abcäüö▒▒▒▒zdjheäöü
```

I've tried many solution approaches like "use locale", other encodings, explicit encoding via "use Encode" and so on.

It seems that in a character like `á` only 1 of the 2 bytes is replaced. If I change my replacement to this:

```
$string =~ s/[^A-Za-z0-9öäü]/_/g;
```

I get the following output:

```
▒_▒_▒_▒_▒_ö▒_▒_▒_ü▒_▒_▒_▒_▒_▒_▒_▒_▒___▒_▒_▒_▒_▒_abcäüö▒_▒_▒_▒____zdjheäöü
```

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Make sure to save your file as UTF8, and use `use utf8;` (or BOM).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> It seems that in a character like "á" only 1 of the 2 bytes is replaced.

1. Decode inputs.

   You didn't tell Perl your script is encoded using UTF-8. Add

   ```
   use utf8;
   ```
2. Encode output.

   You'll also need the following to encode the output:

   ```
   use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';
   ```

Comment: Although I do not quite understand why, but it works. I've tried it with "use utf8;" and "binmode STDOUT, ":encoding(UTF-8)";" before, like M42 explained. Then the replacement works fine, but all other output has an wrong encoding. Only with your second step, it works as desired. Thank you very much!

Comment: Re "I do not quite understand why, but it works", The file contained `my $scalar = "Ã¡Ã©Ã­Ã³...";` as far as Perl was concerned since you didn't tell it you used UTF-8.

Comment: How could this be. The encoding of the file is UTF8. I've converted it with notepad++ to be sure.

Comment: The _file_ may be UTF-8, but you didn't tell _Perl_ that.  By default, Perl assumes files are ISO-8859-1.

Comment: Thx. I had have such a problem never before. All my files and scripts of the last few years are working as they should. So the one and only way to run a clean utf-8 system, is to convert all files to utf-8 and tell perl that these files are utf-8, too? I know that I shouldn't use  stackOverflow as a chat, but that's my last question to this topic ;-)

Comment: It's common for certain encoding bugs cancel each other out.

Answer (score 0):

Put this line at the begining of the script:

```
binmode STDOUT, ":encoding(UTF-8)";
```

See the [doc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunifaq.html#What-is-a-%22wide-character%22?)

Comment: I've tried your solution, and here is my output: Ã_Ã_Ã_Ã_Ã_Ã_Ã_Ã_Ã_Ã_Ã_Ã_Ã_Ã_Ã_Ã_Ã_Ã_Ã___Ã_Ã_Ã_Ã_Ã_abcÃ¤Ã_Ã_Ã_Ã_Ã_Ã____zdjheÃ¤Ã_Ã_

Comment: Since OPs replace is not working properly Perl is getting some of the encodings wrong for the input string and/or the replacement. (Without this his output would have issues too when he gets the other utf8 stuff right.)